# In a particulary case, probability convergence implies $L^p$ convergence

Tags: probability, measure-theory, convergence-divergence

Let be $X_n$ with $|X_n|< K$, $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$. I would like to prove that 
$$X_n  \xrightarrow{P} 0 \implies \lim E[|X_n|^p] = 0  $$ 
First, we have that  $|X_n|^p< K^p$ and I would like to use the dominance convergence theorem to prove that $\lim_{n\to \infty} E[|X_n|^p] = 0 $. But for this, I will have to show, in some way, that $X_n  \xrightarrow{P} 0$ implies almost everywhere convergence, that is

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} P(|X_n|>\epsilon) = 0, \forall \epsilon>0 \implies  X_n \xrightarrow{a.e} 0.$$

Some idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $\epsilon>0$, let $A_{n}=\{x~:~\lvert X_{n}(x)\rvert>\epsilon\}$, let $n$ be a sufficiently large integer such that $P(A_{n})<\epsilon$, and let $B=A^{c}$. Integrate $\lvert X_{n}\rvert^{p}$ over $A_{n}$ and $B$ separately to see that the integral is less than $K^{p}\epsilon+\epsilon^{p}$.

Answer (score 1):

Since $X_n\xrightarrow{p}0$, for every subsequence $n_k$ there exists further subsequence $n_{k'}$ s.t. $X_{n_{k'}}\xrightarrow{a.s.}0$ and by the DCT, $\mathsf{E}|X_{n_{k'}}|^p\to 0$...